# How to random position from UIButtons has created by storyboard?[swift Xcode]

Tags: swift, xcode, random, uibutton, shuffle

I created 12 UIButtons by storyboard, in my program, these buttons represent  cards,I want to random the buttons' position for shuffling the cards.please do me a favor, give a way or idea to achieve it.

[my buttons problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G45vu.png)

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
lazy var game = Concentration(numberOfPairsOfCards: numberOfPairOfCards) //引入model Concentration
var numberOfPairOfCards : Int {
    return (cardButtons.count + 1) / 2  //read only computed properties可以省略get{}
}
var flipCount = 0 {
    didSet {
        flipsCountLabel.text = "Flips: \(flipCount)"
    }

}
@IBOutlet var cardButtons: [UIButton]!



@IBOutlet weak var flipsCountLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func touchCard(_ sender: UIButton) {
    flipCount += 1

    if let cardNumber = cardButtons.index(of: sender) {
         game.chooseCard(at: cardNumber)
        updateViewFromModel()

    } else {
        print("somthing wrong")
    }


}
```

I have done the job.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    var buttons = [UIButton]()
    for index in cardButtons.indices {
        buttons.append(cardButtons[index])
    }

    for index in cardButtons.indices {
        cardButtons[index] = buttons.remove(at: buttons.count.arc4random)
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you share some code you have tried? You can find information about how to ask Good questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry for this,I will fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the buttons to an array, shuffle the array and then loop through it and place the buttons. A better solution would be to create a UICollectionView instead though.

Comment: Could you show me some code for how to add the buttons to an array with swift?

Comment: OK,according to your nice advice, I have made it. thanks you a lot.